# Exibir mensagem de erro ao digitar telefone

Tags: javascript, alert

Tenho um formulário e preciso que este campo

```
<label class="labVal210Esq">Telefone:
<input type="text" class="val120Dir"
name="TxtTelefone" /> </label>
```

No caso é o telefone, que ele apresente as seguintes mensagens de erro:
Caso o usuário digite menos de 8 dígitos que apareça uma mensagem de erro, um `alert("Telefone tem de ter 8 dígitos!")`.

Caso o usuário digite "-" que é um carácter inválido, um alert com = `alert("Carácter inválido, somente dígitos).`

E caso o número seja válido (8 dígitos) não apareça nada.

Meu código:

```
function VerificaTelef (ident, campo) {
var i, c;
var strTel = campo.value;
if ( strTel.length !=8 ){
alert ("Telfone tem de ter 8 dígitos!");
return false;
}
for (i = 0; i < 8; i++ ){
c = strTel.charAt (i);}
if ( (c < '0') || (c > '9')){
alert("Telefone só pode ter 8 dígitos");
return false;
}}
return true;
}
```

Não está dando certo.

A referência no HTML para o javascript tem que ser pelo onKeyup se possível, pois o javascript tem que verificar após o usuário digitar.

Atenciosamente,

Gabriel

Comment: O que é a variável ident?

Answer (score 1):

Eu sugiro utilizar a validação suportada pelo próprio browser. Isto só funciona se o browser suportar HTML5

```html
<form>
<input type="tel" name="telefone" maxlength="8" minlength="8" 
       pattern="[0-9]*" title="Digite apenas números">
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

Para usar algo mais completo ou diferente você pode continuar a usar o evento onchange com esta validação automática:

```html
<form>
<input type="tel" name="telefone" maxlength="8" minlength="8" 
       pattern="[0-9]*" title="Digite apenas números" onchange="if(!this.validity.valid)alert('O telefone não é válido')">
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode fazer assim:

```js
document.getElementById('telefone').onblur = function() {
  validaTel(this);
};

function validaTel(el) {
  if (el.value.length < 8) {
    alert("Telefone tem de ter 8 dígitos!");
  } else if (el.value.length > 8) {
    alert("Telefone só pode ter 8 dígitos");
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="telefone">
```

Lembrando que fica mais pratico limitar o tamanho pelo html usando maxLength, e usar o onblur evita que mostre toda hora a mensagem durante a digitação.

Comment: Mas se eu usar o maxLength, não vai aparecer o alert, o mais importante é aparecer o alert, queria um negócio bem simples só pra aparecer o erro se o número não for digitado de acordo com que eu perguntei, sacas?

Comment: @Ab0ut só tirar ele.

Comment: Amigão até funcionou, mas poderia adicionar uma função para verificar se há alguma letra diferente de dígito?

Answer (score 1):

Para complementar vou deixar uma versão mais completa da resposta do @GabrielRodrigues.

Fiz utilizando o [Plugin jQuery Mask](https://plugins.jquery.com/mask/), acredito que aumente a usabilidade do campo já que ele já vem formatado, além disso ele também "proíbe" que sejam digitados letras ou qualquer caractere que não seja digito.

```js
jQuery("input.telefone")
  .mask("(99) 9999-9999?9")
  .focusout(function(event) {
    var target, phone, element;
    target = (event.currentTarget) ? event.currentTarget : event.srcElement;
    phone = target.value.replace(/\D/g, '');
    element = $(target);
    element.unmask();
    if (phone.length > 20) {
      element.mask("(99) 99999-999?9");
    } else {
      element.mask("(99) 9999-9999?9");
    }
  });

document.getElementById('telefone').onblur = function() {
  validaTel(this);
};

function validaTel(el) {
  if (el.value.length < 11) {
    alert("Telefone tem de ter 11 dígitos!");
  } else if (el.value.length > 20) {
    alert("Telefone só pode ter 11 dígitos");
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://digitalbush.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/jquery.maskedinput.js"></script>
Telefone:
<input type="text" class="telefone" id="telefone">
```

Comment: Certo, só não confunda JavaScript com jQuer e procure verificar quais são as Tags relacionadas à pergunta.

Answer (score 0):

Galera consegui! 
Usei a resposta do @Bruno Costa e o Js do @Gabriel Rodrigues.
Ficou simplesmente assim:

```
<input type="text" id="telefone" value="12345678" onchange="if(!this.validity.valid)alert('O telefone só pode conter dígitos'); if(value.length < 8) 
    alert('Telefone tem de ter 8 dígitos!');" type="tel" name="telefone" pattern="[0-9]*" class="val120Dir">
```

Comment: Não esqueça de dar +1 nas respostas que te ajudaram e a que levou a resolver, marcar como solução, assim você mantem os membros motivados a ajudar ;)

Comment: Dá uma olhada no patern ele não é compatível com todos os navegadores